# How do I use catkin in a directory containing a space character?

Tags: ros, catkin, bash, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use catkin in a directory that contains a space, when pressing `TAB` to trigger the tab completion the script fails:

```~/SpiderOak Hive/catkin_workspace/devel$ roslaunch fanuc_m10ia_support find: `/home/dell/SpiderOak': No such file or directory find:` Hive/catkin_workspace/src/fanuc/fanuc_m10ia_support': No such file or directory

```
My `.bashrc` looks like:
```

source ~/SpiderOak\ Hive/catkin_workspace/devel/setup.bash

```
Clearly a `\` is missing somewhere to escape the space character, where should I add it?
I've tried adding it to line 3 of `setup.sh` (it does not change anything):
```

: ${_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR:=/home/dell/SpiderOak\ Hive/catkin_workspace/devel}

```
---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216626/how-do-i-use-catkin-in-a-directory-containing-a-space-character?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2015-08-27


Post score: 1

---

### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-27**:\
is that space so necessary? why making your life hard !

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2015-08-27**:\
Yes, the `Spider Oak` app does not allow to rename the sync directory.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-27**:\
Can you try doing ln -s /SpiderOak\ Hive/ SpiderOak_Hive  and then work with that static link which points to the original folder but with a name containing no spaces.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2015-08-27**:\
Nice idea but it doesn't work either!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-08-29**:\
This is very easily reproducable (just create a workspace path that includes a space in it) and I would say this is a bug. Could be that somewhere some script does not properly quote paths. Adding escape chars everywhere would only be a *work around*. I'd report this at the `ros_comm` tracker.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2015-08-29**:\
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/658
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not possible to use catkin in a directory containing special characters for the moment, an issue is opened here if you want more information and/or want to contribute to ROS by adding this feature:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/658

My question was closely related to SpiderOak; an alternative solution is to not use the SpiderOak Hive and setup sync folders instead. See https://spideroak.com/forum/search/?q=rename+hive for more details.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Don't use file names with spaces on Linux. It breaks lots of tools, not just ROS.

If you have a tool which uses spaces in the file name, you could try making a symlink around the directory name with a space; for example:

```
cd ~
ln -s /home/dell/SpiderOak\ Hive/catkin_workspace
```

Now you can:

```
cd ~/catkin_workspace
catkin_make
```

etc without the space in the path name

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1